# Sensors in smartphones

Tags: android, android-sensors

I would like to learn on how the sensors like accelerometer, pressure sensors, light sensors and the rest actually work in smartphones. Say if we have onSensorChanged for an accelerometer in android, what actually is happening internally in order to render the output.

Can anyone help with me with resources that I can find about this.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you asking from a hardware perspective or a software perspective? Software: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorListener.html

Comment: Thanks. That did help. I do want to know both hardware as well as software details. The software details are good in the link provided. A much deeper insight would be better.

Answer (score 0):

It might be interesting to learn about the hardware itself, but what I find intriguing are the methods for taking the data from the sensor and making it useful. It's a whole field: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processing also check this out: http://www.dspguide.com

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to a technical talk explaining many details about sensors. The session no tonly gives more details than usual about sensors, but also covers some interesting topics such as sensor integration. You can find the video in the provided [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k)